# Laptop wont cast youtube to TV. Identical laptop will?

Tags: desktop-recording

I have two identical laptops with identical synced browsers, on the same network. One will cast youtube to TV and the other wont. As far as I know even the extensions and software are the same. What can I do to get the other laptop to cast.

Comment: Dumb question: Are those in the same network?

Comment: A must read is https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask What version of Ubuntu are you using? The tag you used does not fit the question, what are you recording?